# How do I start a program on my desktop from an SSH session?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

Lets say I want to start Teamviewer on my home-desktop which I currently only have SSH access to. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's as easy as telling the program to run on your the default display `0` for your desktop X server, which is normally also `0`.

For example, to start `shutter`, you would execute this from the SSH terminal:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 shutter &
```

Comment: Argh. All my life I just got the DISPLAY variable wrong (no :). Thanks

Comment: That's actually implicitly `localhost:0.0`, although this just uses a Unix socket to connect instead of a TCP socket. In theory you could throw in an IP in there to start on a remote X server, although in practice this is almost always tunneled over SSH...